# How do I deal with Dark Pit players as Samus/D. Samus?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

The following is an inquiry about the Samus vs D. Pit match up specifically.

The problems I face in this match up specifically are:

- The speed of Pit's arrows makes them better for spamming than my rockets
- Pit's side special has more range than Samus' grapple hook (z-air or grab) and dash attack which makes it hard to close the gap without getting hit
- I can't use projectiles to force him to jump since Pit/D.Pit can deflect them back instead.

How can I mitigate the effectiveness of these moves specifically?

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? Is it because I'm too broad in the first part or is it because of how specific I am in the safe-to-ignore part?  what should I change?

Comment: Metagame questions are fine; the problem is that everyone learns differently, and that limits the usefulness of this question. It becomes very opinionated as to what is actually useful.

Comment: @scohe001 Thanks!  I'll try asking there instead.

Comment: Voting to re-open -- while everyone can learn differently, @Robotex has re-edited his question to be very specific. It would be no different than someone asking how to play G&W vs Snake, or character specific matchups if that is what they struggle with. As such I see a legitimate question that still fits the site's guidelines.

Comment: Re-opening as the new version of the question seems fine.

Comment: A little edit was all this question needed, hopefully you get some good answers! Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3):

#### Problem 1: Spamming

Projectile spam will not help you in this match-up. You need to approach fairly quickly, (unless you are charging your neutral special) which isn't match-up specific, just a Samus thing. What your projectiles could be useful for is approaching - they force your opponent to reflect, shield, or jump. Of course, you should anticipate a reflection with a spot dodge, but not before you've managed to get a little closer to your opponent.

Dealing with Dark Pit's arrows isn't the easiest - parrying each one is probably your best bet, though. You might want to practice this some.

#### Problem 2 - spacing

Ah, Pit's side-b. The bane of life.

No really, it can be super annoying. Still, zair is a good option, especially when fastfalled. Predicting when Pit will use Side-B is half the battle - it is very punishable.

A good strategy might be to come in carefully with zairs that don't actually hit your opponent, but do keep them at bay, and too close to arrow-spam. Patiently wait until *they* close that last little gap with an attack, then shield (hopefully parry) and you have your opening.

#### Problem 3 - reflectors

This one hurts, too. However, you can use it to your advantage. By shooting some obvious projectiles (rockets) as reflector bait, you can sometimes run in and take advantage of the reflector's very long end-lag. Maybe rocket-> down-b roll in -> grab?

#### Final thoughts

You might also want to have a counter-pick for this match-up, since it is unfavorable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd play this much more defensively, you've got some very good things going for you.

Your mines can, and should, be used to zone him a bit, to alter your fallspeed etc and/or simply to damage him. When he uses his side-B, you may be able to dodge him (actually not very hard once you know the timing, up-dodge might work the best) and then punish him.

About the grab, you should mix slow rockets with the faster ones, they will cancel each other if one of them is reflected, which let him open for retaliation, and grab. You could also rush him and grab him before the reflect, and it should be very fine.

About his arrows, it's annoying but once you learn the timing you'll be able to "perfect" block it and it's less of an issue afterwards.

Your down-a also has a wide area of effect, if it looks like you're going for a point-blank b-neutral and he tries his reflect or block etc, this attack might work better.